# Android : Protecting image drawables from decompilation

Tags: android, encryption

I am having a dilemma right now. I'm making a game for android using native java. It's a visual novel game so it has a lot of images (characters, scenes, etc). My problem is that I won't be able to port to iOS anytime soon(I can't afford iOS yet), and I'm afraid that someone will decompile my apk, recreate the game, and port it to iOS.

What can I do to prevent this, or at least make it harder for the theft. I've been using ProGuard for my APKs but that won't protect the drawables, or does it?

I'm thinking of saving an encrypted image (the image is scrabled) instead of the original image, then during run time as each scene loads, I will be decrypting the image so it'll display the original one. I have no idea how to do this though. Anyone ever tried doing it?

Comment: Try dexguard.. That will protect your code and images

Comment: It doesn't protect images.

Answer (score 0):

Try AndResGuard this which will also work with all the resource type(such as drawable、layout、string...).

dependency you need to use :

```
 classpath 'com.tencent.mm:AndResGuard-gradle-plugin:1.2.17'
```

It also help us to reduce apk size try this out.